# Why is MS Access repeating the details section?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access 2010, and I created a form that then produces a report. Because it is designed to print on a label instead of a regular piece of paper, the entire report is smaller than usual, with the Report Header being .5" tall and the Details section being 1.5" tall. The label is 2" tall with no border on the top or bottom. When I go to Layout View, it shows the Report Header once at the top and then the Details section many times. I'm not sure exactly how many times it repeats, but it appears to be at least 100. Putting in page numbers shows that it thinks that the entire thing is one page, instead of being 100+ pages. I tried both forcing a line break and having it create a new row after the section, neither of which changed anything. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

This is a screenshot of a sample label:

[image: Label Problem]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem by opening the Report in design view and adjusting either the page size or the margins so that they only accommodate one label per page.

Those settings are found and adjusted as follows:

- **Page Size:** Page Setup (tab in Access ribbon) > Page Size (ribbon group) > Size
- **Margins:** Page Setup (tab in Access ribbon) > Page Layout (ribbon group) > Page Setup > Print Options

Comment: When I try to change the page size, a small white circle appears in the bottom left corner of the button, and no menu appears.

Comment: That's odd -- but as a work-around, you can also get to the Page Size information in the Page Setup dialog (similar to Margins in my answer, except under the Page tab of that dialog box). In my installation there's not a custom page size, though; if yours is the same, you'll probably need to make both adjustments: (1) Select a page size that words for you and then (2) reduce the margins until it allows space for just one label.

Comment: The only size choice is "User defined", but I can't find anywhere to define the size.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have some or all of your data fields in the page header portion of the report.  This just happened to me.  I had some parent data, and some child data, and I put the parent data in the page header portion, and child subform in the detail area, and this caused the problem.

All the data should be in the details section.  Perhaps shoot us an image if the report in design mode, so we can see what is where, if you need more help on it.

Answer (score 0):

To preview what is printed use the`Print Preview`! The`Layout View`is designed to [edit the report](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/modify-edit-or-change-a-report-2837aea7-0ee5-4c81-9f0f-5cf324c2c3bd) (e.g. resize/move controls) while displaying the the data, but the pages are not câlculated and the`Details Section`is repeated the for each record to one page.

The `Print Preview`limits the `Details Section` to fit the Page-Size, but you can't edit the report.